# Can you animate to location of a generic physics constraint?

Tags: physics, constraints

I have two rigid bodies (one active and one passive) connected through a Generic physics constraint, and would like to animate the location of the passive rigid body so that the other follows. Imagine a BigCube (passive rigid body) carrying a LittleCube (active rigid body) by means of a rope. Like a drone carrying an object with a rope or net.
I cannot seem to manage to get the location of the BigCube or the location of the constraint to keyframe to move in animation, so that the LittleCube follows.
Thank you very much!

Comment: i don't get it. You described what you have done, and that's how it works. If this doesn't work, pls provide blend file so we can check it out on our own, since you didn't show us any technical settings you made, you just described roughly what you did. thx.

Comment: Have you checked _Animated_ on the passive rigid body? Because without, although you can animate the movement of the cube with keyframes, it will only be taken into account by the rigid body simulation with _Animated_ enabled. Otherwise the passive body will be treated as if it stood still.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann That's it, that solved my problem! Thank you very much. How can I accept your reply as the answer?

Comment: @Steffen Comments can only be upvoted, but not accepted as answer. I have written a proper answer below so this question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to enable the *Setting* > *Animated* for the passive rigid body object. To animate the object itself with keyframes this is not necessary, the keyframes will work like on any other object.

However the rigid body simulation will only take the animation into account when this option is enabled (just like on active rigid bodies). Without it, the passive rigid body moves, but the movement will have no effect on the simulation and will be treated as if it was static in the starting location.

[image: passive animated]